# Gephi 0.8.2 does not open in Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, gephi

I installed gephi 0.9 and it worked, but most plugins do not work. So I uninstalled and decided to try gephi 0.8.2.
It is correctly installed, but when trying to open the program, it shows the splashscreen, and it disappears, and thats it. It never opens and gives no error message.

I tried uninstalling, restarting, and reinstalling, but still the same. 
Can someone please help me? Did I do something wrong in the installation? How can I get gephi working?

Answer (score 1):

The following resolved my Issue:

- uninstall older versions of java
- Installed Java 8
- Updated jdk path to jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161"  in gephi.conf (etc folder)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem with the installed Java version. Gephi 0.8.2 doesn't run on Java 1.8+. Check the solution from [here](http://www.clementlevallois.net/gephi/tuto/en/How%20to%20install%20Gephi%20on%20Windows%208.pdf). You basically have to start Wordpad with administrative privilleges and open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Gephi-0.8.2\etc\gephi.conf`.

Change jdkhome to a valid path to your Java 7 installation (JDK) or (JRE). In my gephi.conf it is:

```
jdkhome="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"
```

Save and restart Gephi